# Doxygen stub generator for visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

Simple question. When I was using Visual Studio Code, I found [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen) extension very useful for writing documentation for my code.

I am now forced by circumstances out of my control to use Visual Studio (in particular VS2019) to program, and I have been searching for the last hour to find an extension with comparable functionality, to no avail.

Is there any way to get the functionality of what is basically a doxygen stub generator in Visual Studio 2019?